# tengo un problema y es con el R.raw de kotlin android studio no se que sucede alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-maps, class, programación-móvil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> import android.graphics.Bitmap import android.graphics.Color import
> android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable import android.os.Bundle
> import android.view.LayoutInflater import android.view.View import
> android.view.ViewGroup import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
> import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar import
> androidx.core.content.ContextCompat import
> androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment import
> androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.findNavController import
> com.example.lab7.R import com.example.lab7.model.ubicacion import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*
>
> class Fragment_ubicacion : DialogFragment(), OnMapReadyCallback,
> GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener{
>
> ```
> override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>     setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle)
> }
>
> override fun onCreateView(
>     inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
>     savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
> ): View? {
>     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
>     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ubicacion, container, false)
> }
>
> override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
>
>     val toolbar: Toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbarubicacion)
>     (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
>     toolbar.navigationIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.context, R.drawable.ic_close)
>     toolbar.setTitle("Ubicación Evento")
>     toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE)
>     toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
>         dismiss()
>     }
>     val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
> }
>
> override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
>     val ubicacion= ubicacion()
>
>     val zoom=16f
>     val centerMap = LatLng(ubicacion.latitud, ubicacion.longitud)
>     googleMap?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(centerMap,
> ```
>
> zoom))
>
> ```
>     val centerMark= LatLng(ubicacion.latitud, ubicacion.longitud)
>     val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
>     markerOptions.position(centerMark)
>     markerOptions.title(ubicacion.nombre)
>
>     val bitmapDraw = context?.applicationContext?.let{ ContextCompat.getDrawable(it,
>         R.drawable.ic_localizacion)} as BitmapDrawable
>     val smallMarker= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapDraw.bitmap, 150, 150, false)
>     markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker))
>     googleMap?.addMarker(markerOptions)
>     googleMap?.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
>
>     //--- Mapa personalizaod
>     googleMap?.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(context,
> ```
>
> R.raw.map_custom))
> }
> override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?): Boolean {
> findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.itemUbicacionDetalleFragment)
> return true
> }
> override fun onStart() {
> super.onStart()
> dialog?.window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
> ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
> } }

Answer (score 0):

Si te marca en rojo el directorio `/raw` , esto puede significar que no existe o lo creaste en otra ubicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para crearlo da clic sobre el proyecto con botón derecho del mouse, al abrirse el menú contextual selecciona `New` > `Folder` > `Raw Resources Folder`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona `main` como "Target Source Set"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma se creara el directorio /raw en tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]